# Consultar solamente el ultimo registro de multiples usuarios

Tags: mysql

Buen dia.

En una tabla de Logs, Multiples usuarios hacen Check In y Check Out varias veces durante el dia.

Quiero determinar el tiempo "Total" en el que los usuarios estuvieron "dentro" del sistema (el tiempo que comprende desde el primer check in y el ultimo check out del dia).

La tarea la he dividido en dos pues tengo que ver tambien quien llego a su hora y quien no

La primera parte ya esta hecha, sin embargo la segunda requiere que busque el ultimo check out de todos los usuarios que se presentaron ese dia.

Este es mi codigo para la primer parte:

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE `Date` = '" & Date & "' AND `Status` = 'Clocked In' group by `UserName`
```

Pero no logro encontrar la sentencia que me de solamente el ultimo registro "Check out" de todos los usuarios.

Una captura de la tabla con la sentencia:

```
SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `Date` = '1/17/2018' And `Status` = 'Clocked Out' order by `username`
```

[image: Todos los check out]

La idea es que la consulta solo arroje un resultado por usuario y que este resultado en su columna `Time` sea el valor mas grande.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: intentastes hacer un group by por username, en el time un max(time)

Comment: Lo intente, si, pero me regresa un solo registro. y yo quisiera que me regresara una linea por cada uno de los usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo único que debes hacer es un

```
select username,max(time) from logs 
 WHERE `Date` = '1/17/2018' And `Status` = 'Clocked Out' 
group by username
order by username
```

Comment: Venga IcemanGT ha ido de maravilla, Muchas gracias! Juro haberlo intentado antes, pero creo no haber usuado el "order by username".

Comment: excelente, a tus ordenes.  saludos